# Interchanging func<7>(42) and func(42, 7) template parameter syntax

Tags: c++, templates

The following template

```
template<typename Data, typename Number>
int compute(Data d, Number n) {
    if(n > 10) SLOW(d)
    if(n < 30) EXPENSIVE(d)
    if(n < -10) .. if(..)   // etc.
    return d.abc();
}
```

is sometimes called with `Number n` dynamically calculated: `compute(data, runtime_number)`, 
and sometimes with a compile-time known parameter: `compute(data, 3)`.

If I don't trust the compiler to optimize the latter case (with or without inlines), but trust it enough to make `if(false)` blocks go away I would have to duplicate a lot of code and write a `compute<12>(data)` template. And apart from code duplication, `compute(data, number)` is just nicer and more intuitive to use.

Is there a way to to unify these two?

**Edit:** This is more about *templates*, or template abuse if you will, than about the optimizations a compiler can apply to this case.

Comment: The way I see it, there isn't a lot to optimize here. In the worst case, you get a few extra comparisons with constants (1 cycle each) and maybe a branch or two. Since you mention functions `SLOW` and `EXPENSIVE` being called depending on the result, those optimizations will make no difference at all.

Comment: Right, it is less about these functions and more about removing the `if()..` blocks from the code. And apart from the lightweight comparison function, there is the cost of branch misprediction: There are a lot of `if` clauses (no `else`!), and this function gets called often.

Comment: If SLOW and EXPENSIVE are pure functions, maybe you could cache the results.

Comment: @toting Even branch misprediction (~30 cycles, maybe?) is irrelevant if those functions are actually slow and expensive.

Comment: Yes, all true, but let's assume I *really* care about speed :). Also, I want to understand templates more!

Comment: If your data is also sometimes constant you can declare your function `constexpr` and let it work out the result at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Do absolutely nothing. Compilers are good enough to optimize everything out.